# Make Google Drive in Firefox have the option of uploading a local directory?

Tags: google-drive

When i use Google Drive in Firefox in a Windows 10 computer, I don't have the option of uploading a directory from my local computer to Google Drive.

[image: "New" menu in Google Drive]

But I remember that when I used Google Drive in Chrome browser in Ubuntu, I had that option of "Folder upload" below "File upload".

Can I make Google Drive in Firefox have the option of uploading a local directory?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the problem your are being faced when you try to upload some file onto the Google Drive from Mozilla Firefox.
"Google Drive prompts to install Java-based Folder Upload applet"
If so then follow the given steps:
First of all,
Check whether your Firefox and Java are the latest versions.
If they are not the latest version try to update or install the latest version. Then restart your system and check whether it's working or not, now?!

If the problem is not resolved yet!.
Try to perform the following actions:

- Click the padlock left to the URL (https://drive.google.com/#my-drive).
- Click "More Information...".
- Click "Permissions".
- Under the section "Activate Plugins", look for "Java (TM) Platform SE 7 U" and select "Allow".
- Close the "Page Info" window and now verify.

Hopefully by now your problem got resolved.